# Where can I download a 64 bit windows version of R before v3.0?

Tags: r, version

I have a 64 bit Windows7 machine with R v3.0.1 32/64 bit installed.  When trying to run `teradataR`, I get the following message:

> "Error: package ‘teradataR’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it"

Where can I download a 64 bit windows version of R before v3.0?  Does one exist?

Comment: This looks like the place: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/

Comment: I think you would be better off either trying to reinstall (as suggested), or if that fails contacting the package maintainers and asking if they have an updated version.  I generally find it easier to escape R dependency hell by moving forward rather than backward ...

Comment: You may also be able to move forward by downloading the source version of the package and uploading to ftp:://win-builder.r-project.org to compile a Windows binary ...

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to compile it yourself on Windows (I just did). Install [RTools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), grab the version for Red Hat Linux [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/files/6865/9155/3/teradataR_1.0.1.tar.gz) (creating an account if you don't have one), and run `install.packages('C:/your/path/teradataR_1.0.1.tar.gz',type='source')`.

Comment: Thanks @Frank.  2.15 worked like a charm!

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked! You'll probably want to get up-to-date sooner in R or later, and so might want to contact the package author or otherwise look into getting a version that works with the latest R.